# Is there a way to remove UWP startup tasks entries from the Task Manager?

Tags: windows, uwp, registry, startup, app-startup

I've been looking at **removing** the **startup entries for UWP apps**, but it doesn't seem like there is any information online about it. From what I've discovered, they **don't appear** to be kept **in** any type of **registry**, which surprised me! **Is there anyone who is aware of it?**

**I have attempted** to locate the entry using sophisticated programs like **[Autorun]**(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and **[Glary Utilities]**(https://www.glarysoft.com/glary-utilities-pro/), **but I haven't had any luck yet!**

EDIT :

1. I am searching for a **universal solution**, so please don't propose **turning off the startup from the program** itself. I know it works, but it is **app-specific**, and **many apps don't have the toggles.**
2. Also, don't recommend that I **turn off "Runs at login"** for certain programs in System Settings, as it clearly **doesn't help in removing entries!**